# How simulate control (button) click with left or right key avoiding automatic interactions at listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, focus, keypress, listboxitem

I have 3 ListBoxes, 1 of them lists folders, 1 lists subfolders, the third lists picture files from current subfolder.
1 Picturebox loads the selected item(picture) of the 3rd listbox. 
I have 2 buttons to change previous image or next image calling this function (this make loops of the image list to make it endless):

```
Private Sub ShowNextImage()

    If ListBox5.SelectedIndex = ListBox5.Items.Count - 1 Then
        ListBox5.SelectedIndex = 0
    Else
        ListBox5.SelectedIndex += 1
    End If
    Me.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(lastfoldr & (ListBox5.SelectedItem))
End Sub
```

the button to change to righ is just this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ShowNextImage()
End Sub
```

Then I add function to change picturebox size and get fullscreen when you click the picturebox.

also I add `picturebox_keydown` event to detect keypress of left or right key at keyboard.
**As fullscreen the best idea is change photo directly from keyboard and hide or sendtbak buttons, To make it work, First I try** to call the previos/next image functions directly but it dont works!:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.KeyDown
 ShowNextImage()
 End If
```

**The problem** comes when you press the right or left key: the selected folder or subfolder changes to the next item and the third ListBox updates the list of images, and everithing get loose!!  **at the second try** I use:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.KeyDown
 If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
 ActiveControl = Nothing 'also I try this!
 Button1.PerformClick()  '< simulate the click of the button
 End If
```

but does the same! the current selected folder changes and the list become loose.
Clicking the buttons physically at the form change the images correctly, instead with keys I cant reach to get it work! What im doing wrong?  Im calling (simulating) button clicks wrongly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to receive key presses the `PictureBox` must have focus, which such controls rarely have since you can't really select them.

The best way to do this is to override the [**`ProcessCmdKey()` function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx) of your form and use it to prevent the left and right key presses from reaching any child controls. Doing so will stop your list boxes' selection from changing.

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.Left Then
        ShowPrevImage()
        Return True 'This prevents the key press from reaching any child controls.
    ElseIf keyData = Keys.Right Then
        ShowNextImage()
        Return True
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```